# Prove that L is a subset of M

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I've a question: How do I prove that:

$$L = \{a \in M \mid \forall b \in M, a * b = b * a\}$$  is a subgroup of  $$\langle M; * ; (\cdot)^{-1}; e \rangle $$

I know that for a subgroup, following rules need to be fulfilled:

1) $a * b\in L$

2) $e\in L$

3) inverse of $a\in L$ for all $a\in L$.

But how do I start? I don't really see the values I've and how I can even start with proving the first "rule"...

I hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance!!!

Greetings

Comment: "Proof" and "prove" are different words.

Comment: Ohh ups, changed it now...Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $L$ already indicates that $L$ is a subset of $M$.

For proving that this subset is also a subgroup it is necessary and sufficient to show that: $$x,y\in L\implies xy^{-1}\in L$$

Also it is necessary and sufficient to prove that $L$ is closed under multiplication and the formation of inverse elements: $$x,y\in L\implies xy\in L\text{ and } x\in L\implies x^{-1}\in L$$

Let me show that indeed $x,y\in L\implies xy\in L$.

If for $x,y\in L$ then for every element $b$ we find that:$$(xy)b=x(yb)=x(by)=(xb)y=(bx)y=b(xy)$$

- first equality is based on associativity.
- second equality is based on $y\in L$.
- third equality is based on associativity.
- fourth equality is based on $x\in L$.
- fifth equality is based on associativity.

This gives you a start.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! Looking at x,y ∈ L⟹xy−1 ∈ L, what are the values I can use? I mean there's a a and b in the formula but I don't really see how I can use them...

Comment: You can prove that $y\in L\implies y^{-1}\in L$. This by proving that for arbitrary $b$: $$y^{-1}b=(b^{-1}y)^{-1}=(yb^{-1})^{-1}=by^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for the first item (closure): if $a, c\in L$, you need to show that $(a*c)*b = b*(a*c)$ for all $b\in M$. That will show that $a*c\in L$. Well, multiplication in $M$ is associative, and $a, c\in L$. Can you use those facts to show what you need to show?